# Convert Properties object to byte array in java

Tags: string, properties, byte

I want to convert Properties object to byte[], however i can do with the following piece of code but

```
private byte[] getBytes(Properties properties){
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
    properties.list(printWriter);
    String fileContent = stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
    byte[] bytes = fileContent.getBytes();
    try{
        stringWriter.close();
        printWriter.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        log.error("unable to close resource stringWriter" + e.getStackTrace());
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

but properties.list(printWriter),  will print the string "--listing properties--" string to the console. Need help in finding the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I used a ByteArrayOutputStream to convert a Properties object.  Your function could be modified to be the following -

```
private byte[] getBytes(Properties properties){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        props.store(byteArrayOutputStream, "");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("An error occurred while storing properties to a byte array: " + e.getStackTrace());
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: The above code will print "#
#Sat Oct 27 13:59:23 IST 2018" before the list of properties. We just need only properties. This is an old post, I will find how I did this and update this later.

Comment: Have you found a solution to remove timestamp?

Comment: I think I found some alternative way of doing it. I will check and update the post.

Answer (score 0):

Properties file contains plain text, so to store a byte array you need to encode bytes to plain text. The best way is to use Base64 encodec.

```
String Base64.econdeToString(byte[])
```

And to retrieve bytes:

```
byte[] Base64.decode(String)
```